# How to create a QML delegate with conditional substructure for a heterogenous list in a ListView

Tags: qt, qml

I have a (large) 'heterogeneous' list of json objects that I would like to view in a QML ListView, e.g.

```
[ 
  {"type": "person", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"},
  {"type": "doggie", "breed": "Maltese", "nickname": "Roger"},
  {"type": "person", "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Smith"},
  {"type": "fruit" , "color": "red"},
  ...
]
```

I would like to create a delegate that intelligently renders these items, dispatching based on the 'type' field to subcomponents that know how to properly render that particular type.

Ideally I am looking for a solution that is modular (e.g. create a component for each type in a way that is testable in isolation), and then have the ListView delegate select between these choices in the simplest syntax that is performant and idiomatic.

How should I go about doing this?  In particular, how does one create QML widgets that have conditional structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the simplest syntax that is performant and idiomatic

The "performant" part could be a tad problematic, because JS arrays as models are a quick and dirty approach, which is not very efficient, especially if you have data changes.

You could also use a `ListModel` and run a simple loop to populate it with the JSON objects, but note that this would involve dynamic roles, which are noted to come with overheads.

That being said, you can avoid all this by simply using a loader to instantiate a specialized sub-item in the view delegate:

```
  property var mdata: [
    {"type": "person", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"},
    {"type": "doggie", "breed": "Maltese", "nickname": "Roger"},
    {"type": "person", "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Smith"},
    {"type": "fruit" , "color": "red"},
  ]

  ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: mdata
    delegate: Loader {
      source: modelData.type + ".qml"
    }
  }
```

And then you will have `person.qml`, `doggie.qml` and so on, which can hook up to the data in the same way:

```
// person.qml
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 50
    color: "yellow"
    Text {
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      text: modelData.first_name + " " + modelData.last_name + ", a person"
    }
}
```

This approach avoids the usage of dynamic roles by avoiding roles altogether, instead using `modelData`, which is effectively the same thing as using `model[index]` from inside the delegate.

Note that qml files whose names are not capitalized cannot be instantiated declaratively, so if you need that for some reason, you should implement them this way and capitalize the value of the `type` object property so it can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks! -- this addresses several of my points and also clarifies some misunderstanding.  Can you address 2 things:  

1) Since modelData is not explicitly specified as a property in person.qml, how would you test this component in isolation (assume the capitalization point you raised has been addressed) 

2)  Is there a way to understand why using a Loader like this does not result in performance issues?  Basically, is this common technique used in many similar situations?

Comment: You can just `modelData ? useModelDataHere : provideDummyValuesHere`, as it will be undefined if not in the context of a view.

Comment: Using a loader has some overhead, but it is minor and unavoidable, there is no other way to have heterogeneous data representation.